# How to enable allowGeolocationOnInsecureOrigins in python and QtWebEngine

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I'm making a web browser in Python and PyQt5 and I want to enable allowGeolocationOnInsecureOrigins in my web browser so I can access users location via Google Geo Location API.

**Code**

```
self.browser = QWebEngineView()
self.browser.allowGeolocationOnInsecureOrigins(1)
```

**Error**

```
self.browser.allowGeolocationOnInsecureOrigins(1)
AttributeError: 'QWebEngineView' object has no attribute 'allowGeolocationOnInsecureOrigins'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> enum QWebEngineSettings::WebAttribute
>
> QWebEngineSettings::AllowWindowActivationFromJavaScript
> Since Qt 5.7, only secure origins such as HTTPS have been able to request
> Geolocation features.
> This provides an override to allow non secure origins to access Geolocation again.
> Disabled by default. (Added in Qt 5.9)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

browser = QWebEngineView()
browser.page().settings().setAttribute(                            # <---
    QWebEngineSettings.AllowGeolocationOnInsecureOrigins, True)    # <---

browser.load(QUrl("https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#WebAttribute-enum"))
browser.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: I'm Facing this error

self.browser.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.AllowGeolocationOnInsecureOrigins, True)
AttributeError: type object 'QWebEngineSettings' has no attribute 'AllowGeolocationOnInsecureOrigins'

Comment: Post an example in the question that you run.

Comment: Thank You so much for reply. You need code for examine?

Comment: Sorry, I don't need anything. I posted an example to help you. You write that my example gives you an error. So I suggest post an example which gives an error.